# Python 'string' % [1, 2, 3] doesn't raise TypeError

Tags: python, list, modulo, string-interpolation, python-3.2

Is the exact behavior of the `str.__mod__` documented?

These two lines of code works just as expected:

```
>>> 'My number is: %s.' % 123
'My number is: 123.'
>>> 'My list is: %s.' % [1, 2, 3]
'My list is: [1, 2, 3].'
```

This line behaves as expected too:

```
>>> 'Not a format string' % 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

But **what does this line and why it doesn't raise any error?**

```
>>> 'Not a format string' % [1, 2, 3]
'Not a format string'
```

P. S.

```
>>> print(sys.version)
3.3.2 (default, Aug 15 2013, 23:43:52) 
[GCC 4.7.3]
```

Comment: Just to note, this behavior persists in Python 3.8, and it appears only a list or dict argument fails to produce an error.

Comment: `range()` also fails to produce an error (at least in Python 3.7.3), but generator expressions do. It does seem mysterious

Comment: What is strange is that there is no magic method that dictionaries, lists and ranges all have but tuples (which throw an error) lack. On the other hand dictionaries, lists and ranges all implement `'__iter__', '__len__', '__contains__', '__getitem__'` but simple numbers do not -- so I suspect that one of these methods is involved in the observed behavior.

Comment: @JohnColeman See my answer. Usually all args which can be sed as "mapping" and can be indexed will not raise an error, but `tuple`s are explicitly excluded, probably since the are used for varargs unpacking.

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa That is a nice answer (+1). As a quick test I just wrote a class with a 1-line definition consisting of `def __getitem__(self): pass` and an object of this class works as your answer suggests it should work. It makes sense that tuples are automatically unpacked here thus excluded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the newest printf-style formatting was added, it seems quite a few little quirks appeared in the `%` formatting. Today (version 3.8), this is [documented here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting), but was already mentionned as far as version 3.3 [here](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting).

> The formatting operations described here exhibit a variety of quirks
>   that lead to a number of common errors (such as failing to display
>   tuples and dictionaries correctly). Using the newer formatted string
>   literals, the `str.format()` interface, or template strings may help
>   avoid these errors. Each of these alternatives provides their own
>   trade-offs and benefits of simplicity, flexibility, and/or
>   extensibility.

In this specific case, Python sees a non-tuple value with a `__getitem__` method on the right hand side of the `%` and assumes a [`format_map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format_map) has to be done. This is typically done with a `dict`, but could indeed be done with any objects with a `__getitem__` method.

In particular, a `format_map` is allowed to ignore unused keys, because you typically do not iterate over items of a mapping to access them.

```
>>> "Include those items: %(foo)s %(bar)s" % {"foo": 1, "bar": 2, "ignored": 3}
'Include those items: 1 2'
```

Your example is a use of that feature where all keys of your container are ignored.

```
>>> "Include no items:" % {"foo": 1, "bar": 2}
'Include no items:'
```

If you want further proof of that, check what happens when you use a `list` as the right-hand side.

```
>>> lst = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> "Include those items: %(0)s, %(2)s" % lst
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Python indeed attempts to get `lst["0"]`, unfortunately there is no way to specify that the `"0"` should be converted to `int`, so this is doomed to fail with the `%` syntax.

### Older versions

For the record, this seems to be a quirk which appeared way before Python 3.0, as I get the same behaviour as far as I can go, despite the documentation starting to mention it only for version 3.3.

```
Python 3.0.1+ (unknown, May  5 2020, 09:41:19) 
[GCC 9.2.0] on linux4
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'Not a format string' % [1, 2, 3]
'Not a format string'
```

Comment: The question was originally asked in 2013, years before f-strings were added. F-strings may have been added to *address* the issue, but they were not the cause.

Comment: Though with `format_map` having been introduce in Python 3.2, it would be interesting to dig up a Python 3.0 or Python 3.1 interpreter for comparision.

Comment: @chepner I added a note in the answer. It turns out this actually refers to printf-style formatting, not just f-strings, and was present in the doc at version 3.3: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting

Comment: @chepner for the record I have the same behviour for Python 3.0

Comment: I see the same behavior in python 2.7.

Comment: @L3viathan The logic used in Python 2.7.x is the same as [I found in Py 3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61613669/1170207), once for `strings` and once for `unicode`.

Comment: @L3viathan Yes, I realized that as well. I get it on very old version as well. It's far from being a bug since it makes sense with the logic. But the quirk of tuples being treated separately makes the logic a bit obscure and comes from the initial string formatting syntax with % which still exists but is not the prefered one.

Comment: Actually, tuples are the regular case. Single values are handled specially: use `format_map` (or the equivalent) if possible, otherwise treat it as if it were the element of a 1-tuple.

Comment: This answer covers the documentation part, which reflects the OP

Answer (score 9):

I think the responsible lines can be found in the CPython source code, I got git `v3.8.2`:

In the function

```
PyObject *
PyUnicode_Format(PyObject *format, PyObject *args)
```

in `Objects/unicodeobject.c`, line 14944, there are the following lines

`Objects/unicodeobject.c`, line 15008

```
if (ctx.argidx < ctx.arglen && !ctx.dict) {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                    "not all arguments converted during string formatting");
    goto onError;
}
```

This will give the error, if the `arglen` does not match, but will not give an error if `ctx.dict` is "true". When is it "true"?

`Objects/unicodeobject.c`, line 14976

```
if (PyMapping_Check(args) && !PyTuple_Check(args) && !PyUnicode_Check(args))
    ctx.dict = args;
else
    ctx.dict = NULL;
```

OK, `PyMapping_Check` checks the passed `args`, if that is "true", and we do not have a tuple or unicode string, we set `ctx.dict = args`.

What does `PyMapping_Check` do?

`Objects/abstract.c`, line 2110

```
int
PyMapping_Check(PyObject *o)
{
    return o && o->ob_type->tp_as_mapping &&
        o->ob_type->tp_as_mapping->mp_subscript;
}
```

From my understanding if that object can be used as a "mapping", and can be indexed/subscripted, this will return `1`. In that case the value of `ctx.dict` will be set to `args`, which is `!0`, and so it will not go to the error case.

Both `dict` and `list` can be used as such mappings, and will thus not raise an error when used as arguments. `tuple` is explicitly excluded in the check in line 14976, probably since it is used to pass variadic arguments to the formatter.

Whether or why this behaviour is intentional is unclear to me, though, the parts in the source code are uncommented.

---

Based on this, we can try:

```
assert 'foo' % [1, 2] == 'foo'
assert 'foo' % {3: 4} == 'foo'
class A:
    pass
assert 'foo' % A() == 'foo'
# TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
class B:
    def __getitem__(self):
        pass
assert 'foo' % B() == 'foo'
```

So it is sufficient for an object to have a `__getitem__` method defined to not trigger an error.

---

EDIT: In `v3.3.2`, which was referenced in the OP, the offending lines are lines 13922, 13459 and 1918 in the same files, the logic looks the same.

---

EDIT2: In `v3.0`, the checks are in lines 8841 and 9226 in `Objects/unicodeobject.c`, `PyMapping_Check` from `Objects/abstract.c` is not used in the Unicode formatting code, yet.

---

EDIT3: According to some bisecting and git blame, the core logic (on ASCII strings, not unicode strings) goes back to Python 1.2, and was implemented by GvR himself over a quarter of a century ago:

```
commit caeaafccf7343497cc654943db09c163e320316d
Author: Guido van Rossum <guido@python.org>
Date:   Mon Feb 27 10:13:23 1995 +0000

    don't complain about too many args if arg is a dict

diff --git a/Objects/stringobject.c b/Objects/stringobject.c
index 7df894e12c..cb76d77f68 100644
--- a/Objects/stringobject.c
+++ b/Objects/stringobject.c
@@ -921,7 +921,7 @@ formatstring(format, args)
                        XDECREF(temp);
                } /* '%' */
        } /* until end */
-       if (argidx < arglen) {
+       if (argidx < arglen && !dict) {
                err_setstr(TypeError, "not all arguments converted");
                goto error;
        }
```

Probably GvR can tell us why this is intended behaviour.